# CSS footer all text is centered and shifted to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with keeping the contact and social media links centered but having the footer links to other parts of the site stack on top of each other.

```
#page_footer {
  width: 100% margin-top: 100px;
  height: 180px;
  background: #3b3b3b;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

footer .footer_nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

footer .footer_nav ul li {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  px;
}

footer .footer_nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3b3b3b;
}

footer .footer_nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
}

footer .footer_nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Quicksand", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #3b3b3b;
}

footer .footer_nav ul li a:hover{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
}
```

Here's the Html below with with the social details and then the footer nav underneath

```
   <footer id="page_footer">
      <div id="social_links" class="split">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/" title="@" id="twitter"   class="social">@
          <br>
        <i class="fa fa-twitter" style="color:white"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <ul>
      <section class="footer_nav">
                  <nav>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#solutions">Solutions</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#contact">Pricing</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </nav>
              </section>
    <p id="credit"><small>Site designed &amp; developed by <a href=""></a></p>
        </footer>

     </html>
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML as well?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Can you post an image of your current site and clearly explain what you want it to look like?

Comment: https://imgur.com/5d5PnCk I want the footer nav to be horizontal across the footer rather than verticle and centered

Comment: Are you just trying to achieve a horizontal footer with 100% width? like this http://jsfiddle.net/423ydkyr/ ?

Comment: Yes that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to center the links with the social buttons and the credits?
If yes you are missing

```
list-style: none;
padding:0;
margin:0;
```

on the unordered lists
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gioele/7crwxxz6/)